# help interpreting this line

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I am translating a TED video and I came across this line. Would somebody help me putting this line in simpler expanded form?

> "You know, it's remarkable how universal the gesture is of handing your camera to a total stranger"

Edit:

Since I was asked for edit. All I want to add at this point is I am not totally sure what that line mean. That is the reason I am trying to understand how one can interpret the sentence. Reading all the comments and the answers I now think this sentence has a clear meaning and implications although one can rephrase this in different ways. But the gist or essence of the sentence is simply the same. Thanks everyone for your contribution. Appreciated.

Comment: Interpret it into what? It's already in English.

Comment: Here in Taiwan, everybody is perfectly happy to give their expensive digital camera to strangers & say "Would you please take our picture?" We're not afraid that the average guy on the street will steal it. I'd never do that in the USA, because the chance that the stranger & your camera will be gone in less than 30 seconds is just far too high.

Comment: What @Robusto said. But it *is* a slightly awkward sentence, caused by the fact that the operative noun phrase *("the gesture of handing your camera to a total stranger")* is so long. But the word **is** has to be fitted in somewhere, and splicing it into that noun phrase is probably just "making the best of a bad job". It would be even more awkward putting it before or after that phrase.

Comment: @BillFranke: Which USA are you talking about? Where I live you could do that all day and not lose your camera. People would think you were a doofus, though.

Comment: I left the USA in 1983. I used to live in NYC, LA, Atlanta, East Orange, NJ, (not particularly friendly places), and Iowa City (very safe). People may consider you a doofus for asking them to take your picture like that in the USA, but it's a way of life in Asia: memory shots are very important here. Half of eating a meal in Taiwan is taking pictures of the meals before they're eaten. Then they go onto your FB "Look at what I ate!" page or into your Internet restaurant review. Every waiter & waitress in Taiwan knows they'll be asked to take pictures of customers with fingers splayed in "V"s.

Comment: @Bill: you may be reluctant to do it in the USA, but many people have asked me to take their pictures, and I have not stolen a single camera.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: "You know, it's remarkable how universal is the gesture of handing your camera to a total stranger." That sentence would not, I believe, occasion any confusion or merriment. Better would be: "What a universal gesture it is to hand your camera to a stranger."

Comment: Lies! Don't listen to @PeterShor. I've lost so many cameras in Cambridge it isn't even funny. I suspect it's how he funds his research. ^_^

Comment: Rephrasing into something easier to parse: *You hand your camera to a total stranger. It's a universal gesture. The universality of this gesture is remarkable.*

Comment: @Robusto: Personally, I'd prefer that version too, but I have the feeling some people would see it as a bit "starchy" in speech. I'm not really sure, but I think most people just speaking casually would produce OP's version. Perhaps just because they get too far through without thinking, and suddenly realise they need to get that awkward **is** in - preferably before the end of the sentence! :)

Comment: @Peter: I know [this](http://www.washingtonpost.com/local/drugs-are-the-downfall-of-a-brilliant-law-student/2013/01/31/09ad81be-6bc3-11e2-ada0-5ca5fa7ebe79_story.html?tid=pm_pop) isn't typical, but it's just as American as apple pie & weekly mass shootings & murders.

Comment: @Robusto: Maybe math professors have secret kleptofetishes for items other than digital cameras, as [the late polymath Hedy Lamarr](http://www.hollywoodtoday.net/2008/08/02/5383/) had.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. As it stands this question is off topic (request for writing advice). It is also not clear – translate English to a "simpler expanded form" of English? – and too open ended. Please check out the [FAQ] and edit the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You know, it is interesting how easily you give your camera to a total stranger.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:
"You know,it is amazing how common it is to use certain body language in asking a request for a picture."

Answer (score 0):

"You know, it's remarkable how universal body language can be.  For example, when you hand your camera to a total stranger, everyone understands what this gesture implies."

Answer (score 0):

You know, it's amazing how people worldwide will hand their camera to a total stranger [and ask for a photo].